# gulp-autoprefixer with gulp-sass not creating prefixers

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

So how does the gulp auto-prefixer work?

My understanding is that this:

```
transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
```

should transform into this

```
transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
```

This is my code:

```
var sass    = require('gulp-sass');
var concat  = require('gulp-concat');
var rename  = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
    .on("error", handleError)
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

I've tried moving the autoprefixer before and after the sass, but am not receiving the expected output.

Comment: is there any additional configuration code available for the sass and autoprefixer tasks that was omitted? (autoprefixer should definitely come after sass btw)

Comment: seems like moving it under the sass did indeed fix it. How strange. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What is the output you're actually getting?

Answer (score 2):

Sass is a preprocessor, autoprexifer is a postprocessor. However, your gulpfile is using the postprocessor *before* the preprocessor. Therefore, you simply need to change the order:

```
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    .on("error", handleError);
});
```

Note that I removed the `concat` pipe because the Sass compiler actually does this for you. Just make sure that you are using `@import "foo_partial"` in something like a `main.scss` file (without a leading underscore) and that your partials' file names have leading underscores. If that's confusing, check out the quick documentation [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5).

Also note that I added a `return` statement, as this helps let Gulp be able to tell when the task is complete.

**Preprocessor vs Postprocessor**

The Sass action in gulp concatenates any partial imports and into a single file and then compiles the code into valid CSS. So what was Sass code is now CSS. It is therefore known as a preprocessor, because it does its thing before the code is CSS.

Autoprefixer, on the other hand, works on CSS, not Sass code, so it needs to come after the Sass code has already been turned into CSS. This is why it's called a postprocessor, because it does its thing after the code is CSS.

Comment: First thank you so much there was so much clarity to your post, but i get this error do you know why? "Error: EEXIST, mkdir"

Comment: I edited to have it output to a directory instead of a css file like I had it. See if that works.